# Circumference and area of a circle calculated with integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry

Pardon my poor English and math skills, I'm trying to understand something and I'm not really good at it.

When we calculate a circumference of a circle we use integrals in such way, that radius is constant and the angle is changing, because we sum up only points at the circumference of that circle, right?

When we calculate an area of a cricle we use them in such way, that radius is changing and the angle is changing aswell, because w sum up all the points inside a circle and those at it's circumference, right?

So why when we calculate an AREA of any rectangle we sum up all points at the "circumference" (actually only 1 line that is Y distance from OX) in same way as in first case, but we end up with area?

In other words - how can you use integrals to calculate rectangle's circumference?

Comment: What do you refer to as calculating areas of rectangles using integrals? Do you mean Riemann integration?

Comment: Yes, I think it's Riemann's integration.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to calculate the area of a rectangle using the Riemann integral, because the Riemann integral itself is defined in terms of areas of rectangles. To get a better understanding of how the Riemann integral (and Calculus in general) works, I suggest watching 3blue1brown's “Essence of Calculus” series.